# how to clean the hadoop-hdfs logs under /var/log/hadoop-hdfs

Tags: logging, hadoop, log4j, hdfs

my name node in the hadoop cluster turned to bad health because "The role's log directory is non a file system with less than 4GB of its space free.  /var/log/hadoop-hdfs (free: 2.4GB (11.12%), capacity:21.7 GB"

I looked into that folder and found that I have 5.5GB of log files called "hdfs-audit.log.0" -"hdfs-audit.log.20" in it. I read these files and I really don't need to save these logs. I am wondering is there a way to permanently delete them and never generate them again? ( I tried to delete them manually, but it seems that they came back after a few hours.)

I also tried to add `"log4j.logger.org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.audit=WARN,NullAppender"` in my `/etc/hadoop/conf/log4j.properties`. But it did not prevent those files from "coming back".

Thank you for your help in advance!

Comment: What version of hadoop are you running? Did you restart the namenode after making the change to the log4j.properties file?

Comment: @ChrisWhite I restarted it just now and the 5.5G audit log files are still under  /var/log/hadoop-hdfs. Shall I manually delete then again and then restart again?

Comment: And the version is Hadoop 2.0.0-cdh4.3.0. Thank you!

Comment: Yay! It goes back to healthy after I manually deleted them and restarted again. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Can I manually delete log file?

Comment: Yeah that's what I did and it worked! but eventually you want to change you settings to make it log fewer stuff.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, Hadoop is designed for much larger capacity than the ones you mention, which means that 5.5GB logs aren't that much usually. This explains why the default settings is not appropriate in your case.

You can:

- reduce the number of log files that are retained with the variable `navigator.audit_log_max_backup_index` (usually 10)
- or the max log file size with `navigator.audit_log_max_file_size`

Comment: Thanks!! It has been a while since I posted the problem, but I think we ended up modifying the log_max_file_size to fix the problem. Yeah we were experimenting something on a small cluster so the machines did not have large capacities.

Comment: where do I set these variables? Do i need to restart datanode for these changes to reflect?